# How to update particular part of a model in .dae file using Three.js and Collada Loader

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d, collada

I am using the example of a Elf Girl model provided by three.js in example
 Here is the link on which i am working [ELF GIRL](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=colla#webgl_loader_collada)

I wanted to update this image
[CE2 image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkTZS.jpg) instead of this [CE image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q046g.jpg)

Comment: Why don't you just change the original texture before loading the `DAE`? If you want to retain the original texture for some reasons, you can open the `DAE` and look for the line `<init_from>ce.jpg</init_from>`. You can change the name of the texture right there so `ColladaLoader` will load a different file.

Comment: I want it to replace on runtime on button click.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
var yourObject;
modelOrScene.traverse( (obj)=>{
  if(obj.material && obj.material.map)
      console.log(obj.name) //print all object names, and material map image paths..
  if(obj.name == 'NameOfTheObjectWithTheTexture")
      yourObject = obj;
})
```

on your model to find the name of the objects and materials that have texture maps.

Once you know which object has that material+map, you can load your new texture using

```
   if(yourObject)
      new THREE.TextureLoader().load( "yourOtherImage.png" ,(tex)=>{
       yourObject.material.map  = tex;  //Replace the objects material once the new material is loaded.
    })
```

Comment: I am getting error as Cannot read property 'src' of undefined at (obj.material.map.img.src).

Comment: This is what I tried and its showing me the same error.
 
$("#img_changer").click(function() {
                    scene.traverse((obj) => {
                            if (obj.material && obj.material.map)
                                console.log(obj.name, obj.material[0].map.img.src) //print all object names, and material map image paths..
                  /*          if (obj.name == 'NameOfTheObjectWithTheTexture")
                                yourObject = obj;*/
                            })
                    });

            }

Comment: Sorry.. updated my answer.. i think it's .image not .img

Comment: error exists but its goes if i replaces 
 console.log(obj.name,obj.material[0].map.image.src);
not this isnt the right way i think. it only target first image

Comment: I'm trying to show you how to use .traverse to examine all the nodes in your scene...

try just : console.log(obj.name)

That will tell you the objects names..

Comment: but I am getting error at "obj.material.map.image.src".